# How to filter data as per repeat dates in single array element

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, angular8

This is the type of Object Array i already have

> [    {
>         "date":"12-09-2019 12:00 PM",
>         "id":"1",
>         "name":"hello1"    },    {
>         "date":"12-09-2019 03:00 PM",
>         "id":"2",
>         "name":"hello2"    },    {
>         "date":"12-09-2019 07:00 PM",
>         "id":"3",
>         "name":"hello3"    },    {
>         "date":"13-09-2019 08:00 AM",
>         "id":"4",
>         "name":"hello4"    },    {
>         "date":"14-09-2019 10:00 AM",
>         "id":"5",
>         "name":"hello5"    },    {
>         "date":"14-09-2019 11:30 PM",
>         "id":"6",
>         "name":"hello6"    } ]

But i want new filtered array as per date like below

> [   {
>       "date": "12-09-2019",
>       "data": [
>         {
>           "id": "1",
>           "name": "hello1"
>         },
>         {
>           "id": "2",
>           "name": "hello2"
>         },
>         {
>           "id": "3",
>           "name": "hello3"
>         }
>       ]   },   {
>       "date": "13-09-2019",
>       "data": [
>         {
>           "id": "4",
>           "name": "hello4"
>         }
>       ]   },   {
>       "date": "14-09-2019",
>       "data": [
>         {
>           "id": "5",
>           "name": "hello5"
>         },
>         {
>           "id": "6",
>           "name": "hello6"
>         }
>       ]   } ]

Please guys give me a help in this.

This is what i have done so far

```
public data: any;
    public dateGroupArr: any = [];

    this.data.forEach((item, index) => {
      dataArr = item;
      dateGroupArr[item['date']]['date'] = item['date'];
      dataArr.splice(dataArr['date']);
      dateGroupArr[item['date']]['data'] = dataArr;
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: try creating a list of date's then filter data according to each date and add them to  hashMap<date,arrayList>

Comment: Please provide more details and what exactly have you tried. Kindly read through the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you get this data from a DB / Some REST api service? If its coming from a database its probably a better idea to introduce some grouping and return the results in this manner otherwise it will require a lot of looping and eventually degrade performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this helps

```js
var data = [
  {
    date: "12-09-2019 12:00 PM",
    id: "1",
    name: "hello1"
  },
  {
    date: "12-09-2019 03:00 PM",
    id: "2",
    name: "hello2"
  },
  {
    date: "12-09-2019 07:00 PM",
    id: "3",
    name: "hello3"
  },
  {
    date: "13-09-2019 08:00 AM",
    id: "4",
    name: "hello4"
  },
  {
    date: "14-09-2019 10:00 AM",
    id: "5",
    name: "hello5"
  },
  {
    date: "14-09-2019 11:30 PM",
    id: "6",
    name: "hello6"
  }
].map(item => moment(item.updatedAt).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));

var dateList = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.date.split(" ")[0]))]; // please put this

var finalList = dateList.map(item => ({
  date: item,
  data: data.filter(_item => _item.date.includes(item))
}));

console.log(finalList);
```

Comment: @SurajParise its working in my demo please check is my created data array and yours are same or diffrent

Comment: I got array in subscribe method by api, and i wrote this code in same function

Comment: getRearrangeArray() {
    if (this.dataId) {
      this._dataService.details(this.dataId).subscribe((res) => {

        this.data = res;

        var dateList = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.updatedAt))];

        var finalList = dateList.map(item => ({
          date: item,
          data: data.filter(_item => _item.updatedAt.includes(item))
        }));

        console.log(finalList); 
        
      }, (error: any) => {
        console.log(error, 'error');
      });
    }
  }

Comment: Tried like this also getRearrangeArray() {
    if (this.dataId) {
      this._dataService.details(this.dataId).subscribe((res) => {

        this.data = res;

        var dateList = [...new Set(data.map(item => moment(item.updatedAt).format("YYYY-MM-DD")))];

        var finalList = dateList.map(item => ({
          date: item,
          data: data.filter(_item => _item.updatedAt.includes(item))
        }));

        console.log(finalList); 

      }, (error: any) => {
        console.log(error, 'error');
      });
    }
  }

Comment: `moment(item.updatedAt).format("YYYY-MM-DD")))` dont use this
Please use direct date because after that we are comparing this date

Comment: First you are changing date formate and after that you are comparing that date with original date, it will not work

Comment: But in response i have  updatedAt: 1575301261007 that type of date format

Comment: Please update your post and add original JSON that you have  @SurajParise

Comment: @SurajParise at staring please do map and change date formate and after that use my code

Comment: Thank you so much Jay, your ans is correct but this is not help in my case

Comment: That filter is not comparing number, its work fine with string i tried with name its work, but not with that date number format

Comment: Yes because if you have "12-09-2019 07:00 PM" use .includes and if you have date number use === for compare @SurajParise

Comment: @SurajParise in my JSON i am using date <String> as string so i am using .include in filter for you you are using date <Number> as number so you should use ===

Comment: Oh Great Thanks Jay It helps.

Comment: @SurajParise Thanks and please do upvote if its helpful